# How can I read CSS positions before page display

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

Someone asked me to develop a function which builds up the page layout, animated once, from the center of the screen, to the final positions, while the page has finished loading.
Now what I have in mind (and please DO correct me if there is a better solution) is this:
- jQuery script reads the (CSS) positions of all the involved elements (e.g. the once marked with .buildup)
- The script calculates the center of the screen
- Now it has a begin- and an end- point for every involved layout element
- It starts animating form startpoint to endpoints, at the same time building up the opacity from 0 to 1.

So far so good (at least, I hope :)
However, this should be done before the CSS displays the elements. In other words, jQuery needs to wait before the CSS is loaded (otherwise it can't read the positions), but at the same time, it must intercept the 'CSS display event' because it must not be visisble before the script start its work.

Any suggestions on the last (or entire) part of my question?

Edit: I'm also open for eventual plugins, however, I have no clue on which terms to search.

Comment: Put a mask over the page

Comment: Can you put any sample of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: May be hide all elements using `visibility: hidden`, calculate positions on window.load (to ensure CSS is loaded) then position and animate.

Comment: Shikar, unfortunately no. It's in my head, I have not started yet :)
Salman A, that sounds like a great idea. However it doesn't match my approach of 'Javascript independ building'. It makes the website jQuery dependent (without jQuery, no visibility). At the same time I wonder if it isn't an old fashioned opinion in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate your function only after your DOM is completely loaded. You will achieve this by insterting the function into $( window ).load(); instead of $( document ).ready();

Also be sure to load .js file AFTER your .css file

So first make your elements invisible with css display:none; property and after launching the $( window ).load(); event you can make them visible and send them to their positions through animation function.

```js
$( window ).load(function() {
  $('.hidden-element').fadeIn();
  //and here goes your function for final position animating
});
```